# Backbone: Fire event on any error

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to fire a event any time there is any sort of error on a page. I have the following code:

```
events: {
    'error': 'displayErrorDialog'
},

displayErrorDialog: function() {
    this.$('[data-section=errorDialog]').html(errorDialogTemplate({ message: 'Something went wrong.' }));
    this.$('[data-section=errorDialog]').modal('show');
},
```

The problem is that this code does not fire on every error. Is this not the correct way to catch all errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you register error in events block of a view that event will be confined to the view itself. so rather register the error on window.

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber) {  
};
```

more details can be flown out at MDN site -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror